# Tomcat digest.sh returns different values for same string

Tags: tomcat8, digest-authentication

I need to use digest authentication in tomcat 8.5.
following command returns different values everytime.
    ./digest.sh -a MD5 password

Answer (score 0):

Sample output with Tomcat 8.5.34:

```
>digest.bat -a MD5 password
password:9f62b2616b7716997897f5f7426726d42ed00db0a03f6dd7bcd01ffbd86cfa95$1$4dce3d44ac38c27c25617510c80d5486

>digest.bat -a MD5 password
password:074ed305119e57739648cc511962a056bc3f474cafd7c928838080841cd17f48$1$6e648a798f68635bc5e98778553f5f94
```

As [documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/realm-howto.html#Digested_Passwords) says, the output format is `{input}:{digest}` where `{digest}` is `{salt}${iterations}${digest}`.

The [salt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)) is random. A new salt value is generated for each invocation.